# Lower power supplied by home network after power glitch

Tags: electrical

The other week I was at work when a massive power glitch hit the local area (lights dimming, computers shutting down etc). When I got home, just a few blocks away, something had happened to my home's electrical system; since then the halogen ceiling lights are slightly dimmer, the heater's fan spins more slowly, the toaster takes much longer to brown the same bread (and it too glows more dimly), etc.

I have a power meter provided by my energy supplier, and my 3 kW kettle that used to draw almost exactly 3 kW, now only draws 2.4 kW.

Can anyone guess what might have happened? could it be a problem with my home electrical system, or some substation, or else? It's being going on for a week now. Cheers!

Comment: Time to call your local electric company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would

- Check the supply voltage at a wall socket (expecting 230 to 240).

  - Using a plug-in [Kill-a-Watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt) or [similar device](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/13a-plug-in-energy-saving-monitor-n67fu) or
  - Using a Cat-II or better-rated good-quality multimeter with care.
- Ask neighbours if they have similar problems.
- Report the problem to your electricity supplier.

It might be worth looking for any obvious damage at or near the supply-meter or consumer-unit but I'd be surprised if there is visible damage. Anyway, you'd need an electrician to fix damage in or around those items.

(Assuming UK from user name)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I bought a simple meter and it was reading 205~220 V; called the management company and they had it fixed. Now I get 240 V steady. This is what the technicians found: "the mains transformer for the area failed [because of the power glitch I mentioned] so was replaced, but further lines needed replacing which is why you were experiencing the issues. The line to the apartment was replaced yesterday."